# How to ignore a line with missing data

Tags: python

I have a huge file having tab delimited 0-10 lines. My question is, how to ignore entire row that has missing empty line[4]? my input file,

```
1 GRMZM2G052619_P03 10 56       a b c d e y        
2 GRMZM5G888620_P01 23 67 go:89 f g h k l m     
3 GRMZM5G886789_P02 45 89       o p r s t w
```

So, my final output should look like this,

```
2 GRMZM5G888620_P01 23 67 go:89 f g h k l m

import re
f=open('input.txt','r') 
r=open('output.txt','w')
lines=f.readlines() 
for line in lines:
   new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line)
   go_acc=new_list[4]
   if go_acc != '':
       r.writelines(line)
f.close()
r.close()
```

I think something is wrong in this line if go_acc != '':

Comment: Your regex `\t+` is consuming `\t\t` when `line[4]` is empty, so there is no empty string there but the next field. Either change to use `\t` or count the number of fields as @falsetru suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, since you're splitting the line by the regex `\t+`, the resulting list of strings will not contain any empty strings -- those "empty" fields will simply be skipped. For example, the first line will be parsed as `["1", "GRMZM2G052619_P03", "10", "56", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "y"]`, so the item at index 4 is not `''` but `"a"`.

I think a better approach in this case would be to actually try to match what you're looking for. If, for example, that optional thing at index 4 is `go:XX` where XX is some number, then you could do something like this:

```
import re

f=open('input.txt','r') 
r=open('output.txt','w')

for line in f.readlines():
    if re.search(r'go:\d+', line):
        r.write(line + "\n")

f.close()
r.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip lines (using `continue`) if there are not exactly 11 fields.

```
for line in lines:
    new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line)
    if len(new_list) != 11: # <------
        continue            # <------
    go_acc=new_list[4]
    if go_acc != '':
        r.write(line)
```

Comment: Not sure this is the same criteria as stated in the question. The fact there aren't 11 columns does not necessarily mean column 4 can't be populated (which is my understanding of the question anyway).

Comment: On a side note, I'm sure that `r.writelines(line)` is probably not giving desired output either...

Comment: @JonClements, `file.writelines` accepts iterable that contains string. But `r.write` seems more appropriate. Thank you for pointing. I will update the answer to use `write`.